# SpringBoot static resources not deployed to CloudFoundry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

My SpringBoot project using Jetty and spring-boot-starter-paren and contains a static folder within the resource folder with an index.html. When launching the project locally, the static file is served as it should be but when deployed to PCF, a 404 is returned. Looking into the app folder of the PCF deployment, I don't see the resource or static files at all. Nothing is logged when the 404 is returned.

My manifest:

```
---
applications:
- name: app-candidate
  memory: 512M
  buildpack: the_buildpack
  instances: 1
  path: ./jars/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- name: app-candidate
  memory: 512M
  buildpack: the_buildpack
  instances: 1
  path: ./jars/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is anything special required for PCF to acknowledge the static resources and serve them properly from the SpringBoot app?

Thanks

Comment: Pivotal Web Services (PWS) requires a file named Staticfile in the root directory of the app to use the Staticfile buildpack with the app. https://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html

Comment: I don't want to use the Staticfile buildpack, I have a custom SpringBoot buildpack. That said, I can reproduce this without using it.

Comment: If you don't have `cfignore` in your project then everything inside project directory will go to CF. Where are you placing the static files, are they packed inside JAR?

Comment: I've just looked and the static files are not being packaged in the jar. The static files are in the src/resources/static folder.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot plugin then static files would go insid `BOOT-INF/classes/static` directory of the JAR. Please check again.

Comment: The files have to be in the path `src/main/resources/static`, that they get packaged (except if you have a custom Maven configuration, but then show your pom.xml).

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I added a resource tag to the POM to package the static folder into /classes. I moved my static folder from src/resources to src/main/resources which results in the static folder being packaged automatically. Deploys and works.